# How to tackle Failed to open stream: Permission Failed in php script

Tags: php, android, sql-server-2008, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file from android code using php script to xampp server. I am getting the following error from the php script:

```
/<br /><b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(uploads/null): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\uploadfile.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br /><br /><b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'D:\xampp\tmp\phpE89E.tmp' to 'uploads/null' in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\uploadfile.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br />There was an error uploading the file, please try again!filename: nulltarget_path: uploads/null
```

below is my php script:

```
<?php
// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
    chmod ("uploads/".basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']), 755);
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
}
?>
```

Also the result shows the file name as "null". Can any one please tell me what is the reason for this. Please help me get out of this issue.

All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there can be two reasons :
1. Uploaded file is too huge or upload process has some error. Due to that  'name' value is coming as blank.
2. "uploads" or "tmp" directory is write protected or not allowed to be affected by the user account via which PHP is running.

P.S. : Debug $_FILES to see if $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] gives you any clue.

Comment: @joyd Thanks will try and let you know the status.